# Chart.js - How can ı remove ticks duplicate data

Tags: javascript, charts, linechart

I have repetitive data on the x-axis as in the screenshot I shared for my line chart. When I print to the console in xAxis callback, the result is as follows. How can I hide them?

```
x: {
     ticks: {
     display: true,
     autoSkip: false,
     callback: function(val, index, dates) {
        console.log({dates})
        return this.getLabelForValue(val);
     },
    }
   },
```

```
0: {value: 0, label: 'Mar 02 2023', $context: {…}}
1: {value: 1, label: 'Mar 01 2023', $context: {…}}
2: {value: 2, label: 'Mar 01 2023', $context: {…}}
3: {value: 3, label: 'Mar 01 2023', $context: {…}}
4: {value: 4, label: 'Mar 01 2023', $context: {…}}
5: {value: 5, label: 'Mar 01 2023', $context: {…}}
6: {value: 6, label: 'Mar 01 2023', $context: {…}}
7: {value: 7, label: 'Feb 28 2023', $context: {…}}
8: {value: 8, label: 'Feb 28 2023', $context: {…}}
9: {value: 9, label: 'Feb 28 2023', $context: {…}}
10: {value: 10, label: 'Feb 28 2023', $context: {…}}
11: {value: 11, label: 'Feb 28 2023', $context: {…}}
12: {value: 12, label: 'Feb 28 2023', $context: {…}}
13: {value: 13, label: 'Feb 28 2023', $context: {…}}
14: {value: 14, label: 'Feb 28 2023', $context: {…}}
15: {value: 15, label: 'Feb 28 2023', $context: {…}}
16: {value: 16, label: 'Feb 28 2023', $context: {…}}
17: {value: 17, label: 'Feb 28 2023', $context: {…}}
18: {value: 18, label: 'Feb 28 2023', $context: {…}}
19: {value: 19, label: 'Feb 28 2023', $context: {…}}
20: {value: 20, label: 'Feb 28 2023', $context: {…}}
21: {value: 21, label: 'Feb 27 2023', $context: {…}}
22: {value: 22, label: 'Feb 27 2023', $context: {…}}
23: {value: 23, label: 'Feb 27 2023', $context: {…}}
24: {value: 24, label: 'Feb 27 2023', $context: {…}}
25: {value: 25, label: 'Feb 27 2023', $context: {…}}
26: {value: 26, label: 'Feb 27 2023', $context: {…}}
27: {value: 27, label: 'Feb 26 2023', $context: {…}}
28: {value: 28, label: 'Feb 26 2023', $context: {…}}
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKxH1.png)

I've tried but I couldn't do it

Comment: You may use something like `if(dates[index-1]?.label===dates[index].label) return '';` in the callback to display just the first one of a repeated series. I am however curious what is the general configuration of your chart so that you avoid the "merging" of same label values that chart.js does, e.g., this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bmtcg4r6/)

Comment: @kikon actually I have data like this https://jsfiddle.net/tezqchyr/ .

Comment: Thanks, I finally made it work so I could experiment with my idea. `dates` is useless, as its `label`s  are populated after the callback is executed, so one has to come to the `labels` as they are defined before the creation of the chart -- `if(labels[index-1]===labels[index]) return '';`, or get them from the `chart` object: `if(this.chart.data.labels[index-1]===this.chart.data.labels[index]) return '';`. I put these in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```js
callback: function(val, index, dates) {
    if(labels[index-1]===labels[index]){
        return '';
    }
    return this.getLabelForValue(val);
}
```

in the x axis ticks callback to only keep the first occurrence of a repeated tick label ([fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/n07wh4j6/1/)).

If the (user defined) array of `labels` is not directly accessible, it can be retrieved from the chart, e.g., as `this.chart.data.labels`.

To make things clearer, you may want to keep the first and last occurrences of a label, in which case you may use the condition

```js
    if(labels[index-1]===labels[index] && labels[index+1]===labels[index]){
        return '.';
    }
```

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/n07wh4j6/3/)

Comment: Thank you for support @kikon. I will try your recommend and share result with you :)

Comment: Hi, What about if we don't have labels?
just have an x-axis that has the date type.

Comment: @GaşBîn - I don't understand what you are saying, the question was just about tick labels.

Comment: @kikon Hi Thanks for the replay:
I do not define the labels, I just define the x-axis as a time, to be defined dynamically,
So I get some labels repeated!!

Comment: @GaşBîn If you have repeated labels in a `type: "time"` axis, it's a different  problem from the one here, because the time axis should normally take care of that by itself. You have some options probably making repeated labels, so please ask another question and post your code so we can see what options need to be changed.

Comment: How would I know if I have removed the correct repeated (duplicate) tick? For example, after I see how tick repeat, I am not certain anymore which of these is the correct. Suppose you have repeated ticks like this: ```[0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,...]```, as you can see, they can possibly repeat at the same interval on the graph, however, they are not the same number, (1 is three times, 2 is four times, etc.). I am sure this error appears because chart.js includes all labels from the intervals between let's say between 1 and 2, but then the label itself is not at the exact position!

Comment: My issue is very similar, but not the same! I have very large numbers (for microseconds), thus I use callback function to divide them to 36000000 to obtain the labels in [min]. In this way the repetitions are not in the label array but they appear on the graph itself (as I have explained)! So, I don't know exactly the correct one, since they appear at equal intervals, and, furthermore they are derived from the originals because are the converted microseconds. If I restrict them with ```maxTicksLimit```, this further complicates this because, then it gives me the labels like: [2,5,7,9,12, ...]

Comment: @MarkoKolaksazov please ask another question and add your code; your problem appears to be quite different from the one here, and might be quite interesting. In this question, there's no matter of labels being correct or not. My answer code does something very superficial: from a sequence of identical labels it hides all except the first (or the first and the last for the second version).

Comment: I already discovered (some days ago) the answer to my question. However, it's not related to this question here, so I won't post an answer. I will search here about a similar question, and I will post there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the maxTicksLimit property which is in the options configuration. Using this property, you can control the number of x-axis labels that are displayed on the line chart.

Syntax:

```
options: {
scales: {
    x: {
        ticks: {
            maxTicksLimit: value
        }
    },
    y: {
        ticks: {
            maxTicksLimit: value 
        }
    }
}
```

}